# What is the fastest way to select rows from a huge database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a huge database of more than 3 million rows (my users information), I need to select all users that have birthdays in the current day.

The birthday column is a `text` (e.g. '19/03' or '19/03/1975') with day and month and sometimes the years.

When I try to select rows with like of left functions it take more then a minute to return the results.

I've tried to use 3 int column for `day`, `month` and `year` and then make the selection but it toke longer to get the results.

Any idea on how to make it run faster?

I'm using SQL Server 2008

Thanks

Comment: First of all: if it's a **DATE** - **store it** as a `DATE` ! That way you can save yourself all the conversions all the time...... Second: if you need to search quickly, put an **index** on that column (and possibly include a few more columns to satisfy your queries). And third: 3 millions rows is **not even close to HUGE** - that's a medium size table - at best.....

Comment: When you used three integers, did you index those columns?

Comment: I have, I am as we speak. But let's not argue Tim.

Answer (score 2):

As marc_s mentions, if at all possible, store this as a date type - it'll make it way faster for SQL Server to perform comparisons on, and it'll be way easier to maintain. Next up, make sure to put an index on that column, and consider including any extra columns if you're only looking up the birthday to select a small subset of the total row.

Finally - and this is a big one. TEXT is just about the worst data type you could choose. The way TEXT is stored, the data isn't actually stored on the page itself. Instead it leaves behind a 16-byte pointer to another page. This other page will then contain the data itself in a record. But it gets worse, that record will be a SMALL_ROOT datatype taking up 84 bytes of space when your data is between 0 and 64 bytes in length!

Thus, what could've been saved as an 8-byte datetime or a 4-byte date now takes up a total of 100 bytes, and causes an off-row lookup for each and every row. Basically the perfect storm for bad performance.

If you cannot change it to a more proper datetime, at the very least, change it to a varchar!

Answer (score 1):

first of all save the date in a format that is supported by SQL Server something like `DATE` or `DATETIME` (in your case I am guessing `DATE` should be enough) once you have that you can use SQL functions like `MONTH` and `DAY` as follows and avoid complex string manipulation function like LEFT etc.

Your query will look like this:

```
select * from MyTable where MONTH(dateColumnA) = '1' && DAY(dateColumnB) ='7' --1 is for january
```

I am not sure if this will solve your performance problems entirely but you can run this query in SQL Query Analyzer and see what recommendation it throws with respect to indexes etc. I dont have a great deal of knowledge about indexes on Date type columns

Comment: For the sake of accuracy, -- (instead of //) is a comment in SQL

Comment: That's the first step - use the **proper datatype**. Second step will be to **index** that column to speed up searches

Comment: @ElJay lol! my hand just reaches out to // when I want to comment irrespective of the language.. :D

Comment: @Baz1nga, I know the feeling lol.  I code so much in obj-c, php and javascript - I do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Most of what I had to say has already been said: Use a DATE type to store the date, and make sure that it is indexed. If you're going to use the three integers to store the date and search by that, then make sure that they're indexed as well:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_MyTable_Date_Ints ON MyTable(intYear, intMonth, intDay)
CREATE INDEX IX_MyTable_Date ON MyTable(BirthDate)
```

If you're wanting to be able to search the user table for birthdays excluding the year, I would recommend storing the birthday in a different date field, using a fixed year, e.g. 3004 - instead of using three integers. You base year should be a leap-year, to cater for anyone who may have been born on 29 February. If you use a year far in the future, you can use the year to determine that a date is effectively a date for which the year should be disregarded.

Then you can search for the birthday, regardless of the year, without having to do a function call on each record, by adding "WHERE birth_day = '3004-12-10'. If this field is indexed, you should be able to return all matching rows in a flash. You need to bear in mind that when searching an index, the server will need to do a maximum of 32 comparisons to find a match in 4 billion records. Never underestimate the benefits of indexing!

I would be inclined to put maintain the birthday through a trigger, so that it keeps itself updated. For those birth dates where you don't have the year, just use your base year (3004). Since your base year is in the future, you know that this birth date doesn't have a year.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    MyTable_key INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    username VARCHAR(30),
    birth_date DATE,
    birth_day DATE
)
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (MyTable_key)
CREATE INDEX MyTable_birth_date ON MyTable(birth_date)
CREATE INDEX MyTable_birth_day ON MyTable(birth_day)
GO
CREATE TRIGGER tr_MyTable_calc_birth_day ON MyTable AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
    UPDATE t SET birth_day = DATEADD(YEAR, 3004-DATEPART(YEAR, t.birth_date), t.birth_date)
    FROM MyTable t, inserted i WHERE i.MyTable_key = t.MyTable_key
```

To update your existing table, run the update as a standalone query, without the join to the inserted table as it was used in the trigger:

```
    UPDATE MyTable SET birth_day = DATEADD(YEAR, 3004-DATEPART(YEAR, birth_date), birth_date)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Result Set instead of DataTable or DataSet. ResultSet is fast when compared to both of these